# How to repair render above lead flashing

Tags: flashing, lead, render

My property has a flat roof extension which joins the original house.

In a few spots the render is badly damaged just above the lead flashing.

[image: render lead flashing]

It looks like the sealant in the photo was applied, ignoring the damaged render. In recent heavy rain we've noticed water ingress in the room downstairs.

I'm a competent DIYer, but I'm not sure what the correct fix is here. If I repair the render coming down over the top part of the lead, will it expand / contract at a different rate to the lead causing cracking and the same problem reoccurring?

How should the render repair meet the lead?

Comment: I would probably use mortar and a add mix to fill the divot the add mix will help with waterproofing and once it is painted it should be as good as the rest.

Comment: In addition to assessing (and repairing) the damaged area, you should inspect the entire flashing run to see if the water may be entering at a different point; it is very common for leaks to run down to areas that are distant from the source...

Comment: wow, I have the same type of damage in my property